# divide 10 cols into 3 css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am  pretty bad in CSS making sort of replica  of this page 
https://www.betterhelp.com/advice/
and this i could i make it

[image]

as reference page i tried this

```
<div with margin left zero>
  <div with 5 col left></div>
  <div with 5 col right></div>
  <div with 5 col left></div>
  <div with 5 col right></div>
  <div 4 col></div>
  <div 4 col></div>
  <div 4 col></div>
</div>
```

now i just want two inline my last 3 images with above 10 col div with  so category list  can come

Answer (score 0):

The thing i understand that you want col-md-4 inside col-md-10

```
<div clas="col-md-10">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help